# load data from grid row into (pop up) form for editing

Tags: extjs, formpanel, loaddata

I read in Ext JS in Action ( by J. Garcia) that if we have an instance of Ext.data.Record, we can use the form's loadRecord method to set the form's values. However, he does not give a working example of this (in the example that he uses data is loaded into a form through a file called data.php). I have searched many forums and found the following entry helpful as it gave me an idea on how to solve my problem by using form's loadRecord method: 
[load data from grid to form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914803/load-data-from-grid-to-form)

Now the code for my store and grid is as follows:

```
var userstore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
  storeId: 'viewUsersStore',
  model: 'Configs',
  autoLoad: true,
  proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: '/user/getuserviewdata.castle',
    reader: {
      type: 'json',
      root: 'users'
    },
    listeners: {
      exception: function (proxy, response, operation, eOpts) {
        Ext.MessageBox.alert("Error", "Session has timed-out. Please re-login and try again.");
      }
    }
  }
});

var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
  id: 'viewUsersGrid',
  title: 'List of all users',
  store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('viewUsersStore'),
  columns: [
    { header: 'Username', dataIndex: 'username' },
    { header: 'Full Name', dataIndex: 'fullName' },
    { header: 'Company', dataIndex: 'companyName' },
    { header: 'Latest Time Login', dataIndex: 'lastLogin' },
    { header: 'Current Status', dataIndex: 'status' },
    { header: 'Edit',
      menuDisabled: true,
      sortable: false,
      xtype: 'actioncolumn',
      width: 50,
      items: [{
        icon: '../../../Content/ext/img/icons/fam/user_edit.png',
        tooltip: 'Edit user',
        handler: function (grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
          var rec = userstore.getAt(rowIndex);
          alert("Edit " + rec.get('username')+ "?");
          EditUser(rec.get('id'));
        }
      }]
    },
  ]
});

function EditUser(id) {
  //I think I need to have this code here - I don't think it's complete/correct though
  var formpanel = Ext.getCmp('CreateUserForm');
  formpanel.getForm().loadRecord(rec);
}
```

'CreateUserForm' is the ID of a form that already exists and which should appear when user clicks on Edit icon. That pop-up form should then automatically be populated with the correct data from the grid row.

However my code is not working. I get an error at the line 'formpanel.getForm().loadRecord(rec)' - it says 'Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'undefined' is null or not an object'.

Any tips on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rec is undefined in your EditUser function. You give an ID as parameter to your EditUser, you need to give the record to it as a parameter instead.

```
//The call
EditUser(rec);

function EditUser(rec) {
    var formpanel = Ext.getCmp('CreateUserForm'); 
    formpanel.getForm().loadRecord(rec);     
}
```

Comment: I tried this but still get an error at the line 'formpanel.getForm().loadRecord(rec)' - it says 'Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'undefined' is null or not an object'.

Comment: Are you sure your Ext.getCmp('CreateUserForm') is right? Check if that is not undefined. 

try this: alert(formpanel), if this gives undefined the problem is there. Might by handy if you paste your CreateUserForm code.

Comment: alert(formpanel) does indeed give undefined. How do I solve this? The code for my CreateUserForm is in a separate file called Edit.vm (I am using Visual Studio and Castle MonoRail). Do you think that is the problem, i.e. that it canot access that form?

Comment: I think the problem is indeed that you cannot query the form. Is the form in the same panel/container. How is your layout built? Is the Form already created when you try to query it? Do you have a possible screenshot?

Comment: 'CreateUserForm' is the ID of a form within a window which is in a file called Edit.vm. I am trying to query the form from within View.vm which is a separate file but in the same folder as Edit.vm (both Edit.vm and View.vm are in a folder called 'user'). I don't think the form is already created when I try to query it but I am not sure. I would like to add a screenshot to this comment but don't know how to do that. Do you think it is better to simply create a new 'EditUser' form within the EditUser function and then load the data from the grid row into that form?

Comment: Yes, 
function EditUser(rec) {
    var formpanel = Ext.create('your_class_name'); 
    formpanel.getForm().loadRecord(rec);     
}